# How to produce functions

Tags: programming, function-construction

I want to produce `n` functions. For example, assume that by giving `n=3`, 3 definite integrals will be created, like the following:

```
In[1]:= n=3;

(The algorithm and Processing )

Out[1]:={ Integrate[f1,{x,x1,x2}], Integrate[f2,{x,x3,x4}], Integrate[f3,{x,x5,x6}]}
```

OR:

```
Out[1]:=  Integrate[f1,{x,x1,x2}]+ Integrate[f2,{x,x3,x4}]+ Integrate[f3,{x,x5,x6}]
```

What is the elegant way to do this calculation and produce different functions ?!

Comment: It's not clear to my why `Table` wouldn't work for you.  Can you give a *specific* example of what your input is and what output you need?

Comment: Perhaps you need `Apply`, e.g. `Integrate[ #1, {x, #2, #3}]& @@@ {{f1[x], x1, x2}, {f2[x], x3, x4}, {f3[x], x5, x6}}`. Then you needn't specify `n`.

Comment: @   Szabolcs : In fact, I have a formulation and I want to use a code to add some terms ( like I've mentioned above ) into my formulation. `n` is the number of those terms. I hope that I could clarify my question.

Comment: @ Artes : Thank you Artes! My problem is different from what you've suggested!!

Comment: Is this closer? `Array[Integrate[Symbol["f"<>ToString[#]][x],{x,Symbol["x"<>ToString[2#-1]],Symbol["x"<>ToString[2#]]}]&,4]`

Comment: @ chuy : Thank you dear Chuy !!! It's an intelligent solution !! This is completely practical ! You can recommend it as the answer !! :)

Comment: @Shellp Sorry, it's still not clear.  What would help is a concrete example.

Comment: @ Szabolcs : Dear Szabolcs ! Could you please take a look at chuy's answer ? ( Chuy's : `Array[Integrate[Symbol["f"<>ToString[#]][x],{x,Symbol["x"<>ToString[2#-1]],Symb‌​ol["x"<>ToString[2#]]}]&,4]` ) . This answer was the closest one to my question !!

Comment: he answered the literal question, but its not likely the best approach to your problem.  Using `f[1][x],f[2][x]..` for example would be cleaner and avoid messing with symbol names.

Comment: @george2079 I agree, I was trying to coax more information if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
Clear[fu, fus]
With[{uq = Unique["fus"]}
 ,
 fu[k_] := uq[[k]];
 uq =
  Function[{x}, #] & /@
   Table[
    Integrate[(x^k Sin[x])/Exp[k x^2], x]
    ,
    {k, 1, 5}
    ]
 ]
```

I picked this example because this integral does not produce a nice result for a fixed `k`. It can be reasonable to want to make a few functions here, as it may be nice to avoid the integrals being calculated again and again. This is very similar to memoization, except everything is calculated up front, rather than when needed.

**Usage**

We can ask a value like this

```
fu[2][1] // N // Chop
```

> -0.0379245

Below is the definition of one of the functions

```
f[2]
```

> ```
> Function[{x},
>   1/128 E^(-x (I + 2 x)) (-4 - 4 E^(2 I x) - 16 I x + 16 I E^(2 I x) x -
>      3 E^(1/8 (I + 4 x)^2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Erfi[(1 - 4 I x)/(2 Sqrt[2])] -
>      3 E^(1/8 (I + 4 x)^2) Sqrt[
>        2 \[Pi]] Erfi[(1 + 4 I x)/(2 Sqrt[2])])]
> ```

Others reasons for posting this answer are to show an alternative to using `SubValues` and to using strings to generate symbols.

**Alternative**

```
Clear@fu;
ReleaseHold@
 Hold[SetDelayed][
  Hold[fu[k_, x_]],

  Hold[Part][
   Table[
    Integrate[(x^k Sin[x])/Exp[k x^2], x]
    ,
    {k, 1, 5}
    ]
   ,
   Hold[k]
   ]
  ]
```

usage

```
fu[2, 1] // N // Chop
```

-0.0379245

Note: It seems like I am the only one who uses `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` in this way. The key is to ignore the `Hold`s while reading and realise that the only thing that is different w.r.t. a usual definition is the order of evaluation. The advantage of this alternative here is that we do not need another symbol to store our definitions.

**P.S.**

Sorry if `Function[{x}, #] &/@...` makes your head hurt :P

Comment: Thank you Jacob !! It's really great.